# How to check if an attribute exists in a XML file using XSL

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

At runtime I can have two formats of a XML file:

1. ```
   <root>
       <diagram> 
           <graph color= "#ff00ff">    
               <xaxis>1 2 3 12 312 3123 1231 23 </xaxis>
               <yaxis>1 2 3 12 312 3123 1231 23 </yaxis>
           </graph>  
       </diagram> 
   </root>
   ```
2. ```
   <root>
       <diagram> 
           <graph>    
               <xaxis>1 2 3 12 312 3123 1231 23 </xaxis>
               <yaxis>1 2 3 12 312 3123 1231 23 </yaxis>
           </graph>  
       </diagram> 
   </root>
   ```

Depending on the presence of the color attribute 
i have to process the values of the xaxis and yaxis.

I need to do this using XSL.
Can anyone help me in hinting me a snippet where i can check these condtions.

I tried using

```
<xsl: when test="graph[1]/@color">
     //some processing here using graph[1]/@color values
</xsl:when>
```

i got an error ...

Comment: Did you use the `xsl:choose` :: (`xsl:when`+|`xsl:otherwise`) instruction?

Comment: Yes i used the xsl:choose ...xsl:when+xsl:otherwise conditions in vain..

Comment: And what is the context node? `/` document root, `root` element, `diagram` element, `graph` element...?

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a simple solution that uses to the maximum such powerful features as XSLT pattern matching and push style processing. :)

Answer (score 37):

**Here is a very simple way to do conditional processing** using the full power of XSLT pattern matching and exclusively "push" style, and this even avoids the need to use conditional instructions such as `<xsl:if>` or `<xsl:choose>`:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="/root/diagram[graph[1]/@color]">
  Graph[1] has color
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="/root/diagram[not(graph[1]/@color)]">
  Graph[1] has not color
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied on the following XML document**:

```
<root>
    <diagram>
        <graph color= "#ff00ff">
            <xaxis>1 2 3 12 312 3123 1231 23 </xaxis>
            <yaxis>1 2 3 12 312 3123 1231 23 </yaxis>
        </graph>
        <graph>
            <xaxis>101 102 103 1012 10312 103123 101231 1023 </xaxis>
            <yaxis>101 102 103 1012 10312 103123 101231 1023 </yaxis>
        </graph>
    </diagram>
</root>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
  Graph[1] has color
```

**when the same transformation is applied on this XML document**:

```
<root>
    <diagram>
        <graph>
            <xaxis>101 102 103 1012 10312 103123 101231 1023 </xaxis>
            <yaxis>101 102 103 1012 10312 103123 101231 1023 </yaxis>
        </graph>
        <graph color= "#ff00ff">
            <xaxis>1 2 3 12 312 3123 1231 23 </xaxis>
            <yaxis>1 2 3 12 312 3123 1231 23 </yaxis>
        </graph>
    </diagram>
</root>
```

**again the wanted and correct result is produced**:

```
  Graph[1] has not color
```

**One can customize this solution** and put whatever code is necessary inside the first template and if necessary, inside the second template.

Comment: @Dimitre Novatchev Is it possible to to use this solution into <apply-template> instructions? I'm generating code from XML with XSLT, and I would like to filter some getter and setter ?

Comment: @chepseskaf: If you mean is it possible to use the predicates in the `select` attribute of `xsl:apply-templates` instead of having them in the match patterns, the answer is positive, but doing so isn't necessary and leads to a more "push" or imperative style of processing, which decreases simplicity, understandability, maintainability and optimizability.

Comment: Sad to see this interesting question with no selected answer although it's 10 yrs old. But I think what the OP wants was `<xsl:template match="/root/diagram/graph[@color]">` and `<xsl:template match="/root/diagram/graph[not(@color)]">`, to process all graph nodes in fact.

Comment: @Fuujuhi, Maybe you are right, but in the SO environment "all guesses are equal". Here the OP doesn't reveal his purpose -- only that he had a problem with conditional processing. This answer shows one good solution to the problem, without trying to guess deeper.

Answer (score 23):

## **Customize the template in one match like this**

```
<xsl:template match="diagram/graph">
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="@color">
         Do the Task
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
         Do the Task
    </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>**
```

Answer (score 4):

```
<xsl:when test="graph[1]/@color">
     //some processing here using graph[1]/@color values
</xsl:when>
```

I'm going to make a guess here since your question is missing a lot of important information, such as the context in which thie `<xsl:when...` appears.  If your comment is correct, what you want to do is process `graph[1]/xaxis` and `.../yaxis`, not `graph[1]/@color` values.

Comment: Yes. For ex. based on the existence of the attribute "color" i need to set some variable say..graph-color. Now i want a simple if-else statement based on whether the attribute is present or not. If true..then i may set a variable as contained in the attribute.Else i may use a default color

Comment: Please edit your post to include more of your stylesheet so we can figure out what you're trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 1):

I don't get it - apart from some slight syntax tweak towards using apply-templates:

```
<xsl:template match="graph[1][@color]">
  <!-- your processing here -->
</xsl:template>
```

There's not much we can tell you without knowing what you actually want to do.

Comment: i just want to process the graph based on the presence of the attribute "color" in the xml file...

Comment: its like    if(attribute is present?)                           process 1;                                                        else                                                               process 2;

Comment: Also this graph[1][@color] doesnt recognise the attribute presence

Comment: Yes it does.  If there's no `color` attribute on the `graph` element, that template won't be selected.

Comment: Yes thats the point. There may be or may not be a "color" attribute in that XML file and the XSL has to check whether there is one.