# how to find out if an attribute exists or not in XSL

Tags: xml, xslt

how to find out if an attribute exists or not in XSL.

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4146648/how-to-check-if-an-attribute-exists-in-a-xml-file-using-xsl

Answer (score 33):

**Just use**:

```
<xsl:template match="someElement/@someAttrName">
  <!-- Whatever specific work when someElement has @someAttrName -->
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="someElement[not(@someAttrName)]">
  <!-- Whatever specific work when someElement has no @someAttrName -->
</xsl:template>
```

**Do note**: In a well-written XSLT code the number of conditional instructions (such as `<xsl:choose>`, `<xsl:when>`, `<xsl:otherwise>`, `<xsl:if>`, ... etc.) is close to zero. In this solution it *is* 0.

Comment: Agreeed +1 for a better answer

Comment: If there were several lines of the same work to be done that match "someElement", how would you implement without redundancy. I am using this solution shown, but there's only one line that's unique between my two templates and several that are the exact same.

Comment: @Bryant, Please, ask a separate question for this. Comments are not good for exchanging code.

Answer (score 21):

```
<xsl:choose>
   <xsl:when test="element/@attribute">
     do one thing
   </xsl:when>
   <xsl:otherwise>
     do something else
   </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

Comment: Correct, assuming that the context node is positioned at the parent of the element in question. (I would tend to suspect that if the poster is having difficulty in this area, then they haven't yet grasped the way the context works in XSLT.)

Answer (score 1):

```
<xsl:value-of select="element[not(@attribute)]"/>
```

if need select some element without attribute