# How to check if an XML element has a certain attribute with XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, transform

I've inherited an XSLT transformation project and this is my first time using this technology.  Say I have this XML:

```
<report>
    <data>
        <group>
            <row>
                <cell email="true">
                    <stuff>Testing@testing.com</stuff>
                </cell>
                <cell>
                    <stuff>Not an email</stuff>
                </cell>
            </row>
        </group>
    </data>
</report>
```

How can I test in XSLT to see if a cell has an email attribute, and/or if the attribute it set?

Comment: I know it's not a XSLT but.. You can do with xpath. Query "//data/group/row/cell[@email='true']" should return cell nodes that have attribute email="true".

Comment: The xml structure is dymanic so that won't work.  I'm inside of a for-each loop of each cell element, which will always be there

Comment: Then try "//cell[@email='true']" query

Comment: This solution helped me solve my problem.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4918837/how-to-find-out-if-an-attribute-exists-or-not-in-xsl

Answer (score 2):

try

```
//cell[@email]
```

for your xpath expresssion. use it as a pattern in your template which would contain some instructions like ...

```
<xsl:if test=".[@email]">
    <!-- structures to generate / further processing -->
</xsl:if>
```

or

```
<xsl:if test=".[@email = 'true']">
    <!-- structures to generate / further processing -->
</xsl:if>
```

the test expression may also contain a pattern like the one from  user1759572's comment - it all dependes on the context where you are going to perform your test and which outcome of the transformation you wish to obtain.

Comment: What you have proposed is no different than `test="@email"`, and be aware that `".[@email]"` is only supported in XSLT 2.0.  The equivalent in XSLT 1.0 is `"self::node[@email]"` but totally unnecessary in `test=` since `test="@email"` is the same.