# xml Find if element has value

Tags: xml, xslt

In the xslt if statement is there anyway checking if an element has a value.
ps Im not sure if it is called a 'value' or called something else anyway as an example:
    value

Thanks

Comment: Is this the same question as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4146648/how-to-check-if-an-attribute-exists-in-a-xml-file-using-xsl and if not, what is the difference?

Answer (score 0):

> In the xslt if statement is there anyway checking if an element has a
>   value.

```
test="elem/text()"
```

will return true when `elem` has a child text node. You will want to use this in conjunction with `<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>` in order to prevent whitespace-only text nodes to trigger the test.